# Why is pygame.KEYUP event triggering when the key has not been released?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, keyevent

I am making a game in Python with Pygame and this is the section of code causing the problem.

```
#Game Mainloop
isRunning = True
while isRunning:
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        isRunning = False

    elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        key = str(event.key)
        print(key + " is down")
        if event.key == pygame.K_w:
            Globals.camera_move = 1
        elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
            Globals.camera_move = 2
        elif event.key == pygame.K_a:
            Globals.camera_move = 3
        elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
            Globals.camera_move = 4
    elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        key = str(event.key)
        print(key + " is up")
        Globals.camera_move = 0
```

My problem is that the `pygame.KEYUP` event is triggered before the key is released.

For example, if I press the <kbd>W</kbd> key down, then the `KEYDOWN` event triggers and "119 is down" is printed to the terminal once.

But then if I continue to hold down the <kbd>W</kbd> key, the `KEYUP` event gets triggered and "119 is up" is printed to the terminal repeatedly.

When the <kbd>W</kbd> key is released, it stops printing to the terminal.

I have looked up problems similar to mine and the closest I could find is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50434460/why-do-i-get-pygame-keyup-event-without-releasing-the-key). The reason why my problem is different is because theirs was fixed by directly connecting with their machine instead of a remote vnc.

I am not using remote keyboard, as I am directly connected to a linux machine. I have also ran the code on a seperate windows machine and got the same problem.

Comment: Please [edit] the code in your question and provide enough of it so that others can run it and reproduce (and perhaps fix) the problem.

Comment: Most keyboards or computer interfaces to them have some kind of autorepeat capability which may be simulating the `KEYDOWN` (and corresponding `KEYUP` events) whenever a key is held down for more than a certain length of time. See the docs for [`pygame.key.set_repeat()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.set_repeat)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pygame.key.set_repeat()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.set_repeat) to control how held keys are repeated:

> When the keyboard repeat is enabled, keys that are held down will generate multiple `pygame.KEYDOWN` events. [...]
>
> [...] To disable key repeat call this function with no arguments or with delay set to 0.

Just call `pygame.key.set_repeat()` to disable repeating keys:

```py
pygame.key.set_repeat()

isRunning = True
while isRunning:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # [...]
```